# Move image back after JS setTimeout has ran

Tags: javascript, html, set, settimeout, intervals

I'm trying to change the transform property of an image so it sways back and forth between it's starting position and the new position that is changed by the function. It runs once and then stays there and I'm assuming its because I haven't specified how or when to return back. Any help is appreciated. Here is my JS code

```
function moveHands() {
var handLeft = document.getElementById("metalHand2");
var handRight = document.getElementById("metalHand");

handLeft.style.transform = "translateX(12px) scaleX(-1)";
handRight.style.transform = "translateX(12px)";

setTimeout(moveHands, 1283.42);

}

document.getElementById("playBtn").addEventListener("click", moveHands);
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="flexBox2">
  <div id="picContainer">
    <img src="hand.jpg" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand">
  </div>
  <div id="picContainer2">
    <img src="hand.jpg" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand2">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Play" id="playBtn">
```

Comment: use css transitions

Comment: Please show your code of button **playBtn**

Comment: in what way? am I simply missing the transition property or you saying replace that with the setTimeout function. also added the button, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a direction variable and toggle it in setInterval

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="flexBox2">
  <div id="picContainer">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/0df/powerlines-1-1389965.jpg" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand">
  </div>
  <div id="picContainer2">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/0df/powerlines-1-1389965.jpg" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand2">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="playBtn">Move It</button>
<script>
  var handLeft = document.getElementById("metalHand2");
  var handRight = document.getElementById("metalHand");
  direction = 1


  function rotator() {
    if (direction == 1) {
      handLeft.style.transform = "translateX(12px) scaleX(-1)";
      handRight.style.transform = "translateX(12px)";
      direction = 2
    } else if (direction == 2) {
      handLeft.style.transform = "translateX(-12px) scaleX(1)";
      handRight.style.transform = "translateX(-12px)";
      direction = 1
    }
  }

  function moveit() {
    setInterval(rotator, 1000);
  }
  document.getElementById("playBtn").addEventListener("click", moveit);
</script>
```

Comment: ah I see. This worked, thank you! Just bc I was curious, I added the setInterval to the rotator function and saw that it worked, but only once. Is there a reason why I need to have the timer and moving functions separated?

Comment: No need to separate just make sure we are using setInterval() and not setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

I used **CSS Animation property** for this

```
animation: 2s moveit linear infinite;
```

This means **linear** animation running ***linear***, **infinite** make animation ***continuous loop***

```js
function moveHands() {
    $('#metalHand2').addClass("animating");
    $('#metalHand').addClass("animating");
};

document.getElementById("playBtn").addEventListener("click", moveHands);
```

```css
#metalHand2.animating{
  animation: 2s moveit linear infinite;
}
#metalHand.animating{
  animation: 2s moveit linear infinite;
}
@keyframes moveit{
  from{
      transform:translateX(15px);
  }to{
    transform:translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexBox2">
  <div id="picContainer">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547014751-009831e5bc73?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand" width="100">
  </div>
  <div id="picContainer2">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546872863-e85d5c3e5159?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80" alt="metal hand" id="metalHand2" width="100">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Play" id="playBtn">
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about JQuery yet but thank you for the input.

Comment: Please check now i convert into css @t_gravell

Comment: Welcomes you too